# Performance Problems

Tags: flowground

This question goes directly to the Flowground developers:

I am testing flowground as a tool to connect to NetSuite. In a test flow I tried to fetch data from NetSuite using 3 NetSuite connectors (plus one Webhook und one HTTP Reply). Everything seemes to work, but if I try to run it with testdata I get a 504 Gateway Time-out Reply in around 7 of 10 tries.
Initially I used 3 NetSuite connectors, then I scaled it down to 2; the success rate is higher, but not at 100%.

So my question is: Does this just take too much time? Is there a way to speed things up?
It can't be a token problem or it would never succeed, right?

Help would be very much apprecciated. Thanks in advance.

If you need more info I am happy to provide.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are using the http reply connector to realize a synchron flow execution in ordinary mode (not as realtime flow).
An important constrain for synchronous flows is that the http response must be generated within 60 seconds. 60 seconds after receiving the triggering request (from your client) the connection between your client and the webhook endpoint is closed by flowground.
The more steps the flow contains the higher the risk that the flow execution takes more than 60 seconds.
So we strongly recommend to run synchronous flow as realtime flows.

Comment: Documentation for Realtime flowS: https://doc.flowground.net/guides/realtime-flows.html

Comment: Try removing "Http-Reply" from the end of the flow. This will turn the flow into an asynchronous mode and it won't timeout anymore.